# Small external CSS file works in IE but not firefox?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and want to use an external CSS for my site. I have created a very basic site and stylesheet and placed them in the same directory on my hard drive. The site opens in both Firefox and IE but Firefox ignores the stylesheet.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The HTML and stylesheet are shown below:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all"/>
    </head>

<body>

    <hr />
    <p>This is a website with a style sheet!</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

The stylesheet:

```css
body
{
    background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
h1
{
    color:orange;
    text-align:center;
}
p
{
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

The style sheet is save in the file `style.css` in the same directory as the HTML file, which is saved in a file called `index.html`.

Comment: try changing the media tag to "screen" instead of "all"

Comment: doesn't help I'm afraid, nor does removing the media tag altogether, thanks though.

Comment: It looks right at first glance.  Any chance the case is wrong in the filename?  Style.css vs. style.css ... that's the sort of thing that IE and FF might get different.

Comment: "all" includes "screen", the only browser "all" would fail is Netscape 4 and previous ;-)

Comment: I just copied & pasted your code into a couple files, and it works fine in FF for me.

Comment: As I've now added below, I discovered the file is saved in DOS format and changing it to unicode worked, don't know if the problem was that index.html was in unicode and hence different to style.css, or if firefox just doesn't like DOS format text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, but I have just discovered the problem. The file style.css was save in DOS format, I saved it in unicode format and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

First, if your doctype is HTML4 and not XHTML, you shouldn't use the  syntax, so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all"/>
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all">
```

Second, your CSS file is probably not delivered as text/css (missing mime-type declaration for .css) by the web server you're testing it on. Does it fail too when you open your file locally?

If this is an Apache server, upload a .htaccess file containing this:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Comment: if you are opening a HTML tag like <link> then you will need a closing tag. Hence, <link /> which is open and close all in one go. HTML is a bi-tag system, what you are suggesting is the opposite.

Comment: WTF? You don't need to close tags AT ALL in HTML! You could avoid closing <head> if you want, because when when <body> starts, <head> is implicitely closed. the <link/> syntax is for XHTML where you HAVE TO close tags. using this kind of autoclosing tag will probably trigger some warning when validating. Verify your sources and please cancel your down-vote.

Comment: aren't we trying to teach good practices on stackoverflow. I don't think people will thank you later on when you haven't closed tags because they are "implicitly" closed. You should always teach good practice.

Comment: According to the tutorial I've just read while learning on www.w3schools.com it states that some tags do not have to be closed but that it is highly reccomended that you always do.

Comment: @ZeSimon, *HTML* doesn't require tag closing, **XHTML** does. `<link ...>` is perfectly valid HTML, `<link ... />` is valid for XHTML. Implied closing tags are a helpful "feature" of HTML to make pages render when the designer made a mistake (or can be used intentionally by a service like google to save on massive amounts of bandwidth).

Comment: @zzzzBov I see your point, however in the midst of striving towards better code readability I would prefer a page where elements are closed properly, I for one appreciate the tag highlighting in most IDEs that shows you the opening and closing tag. By leaving out the closing tag because it is "implied" you are just shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @ZeSimon, `<link>` is a self-closing tag, not possible to have contents, so it makes sense. `<head>` is expected to have contents, so it would be foolish to leave out the closing tag without a *very* good reason.

Comment: @zzzzBov point taken and agreed on the leaving out the closing 'head' tag.

Comment: OK now cancel your down vote, my arguments were perfectly valid, I see XHTML has generated some collateral damages  ;-)

Comment: @zzzzBov, thanks for the link, it has lots of links to useful beginner content. I had assumed W3Schools were affiliated with the W3C organisation.